# get parameter value from IEnumerator function instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

Suppose I have a list of `IEnumerator`s:

```
public List<IEnumerator> routines;
```

Suppose I have this enum:

```
public enum Shape { CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, SQUARE }
```

I have a lot of `IEnumerator` routines that receive a `Shape` as an argument:

```
public IEnumerator Move(Shape shape, float distance){ /* code */ }
public IEnumerator Jump(Shape shape, float height){ /* code */ }
public IEnumerator Fire(Shape shape, float power){ /* code */ }
```

My list `routines` will contain a sequence of instances of these functions (that will be called with `StartCoroutine` later):

```
routines.Add(Move(Shape.SQUARE, 1));
routines.Add(Jump(Shape.CIRCLE, 1));
routines.Add(Fire(Shape.TRIANGLE, 1));
//...
```

Given I've already filled `routines` with all those functions, is there a way for me to iterate through `routines` and find out the `Shape` argument of each function call? In this case, it would be SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, etc.

Comment: You need `Expression<...>` (expression trees) - is it present in Unity3d?

Comment: Yes, from `System.Linq.Expressions`.

Comment: So use expressions as parameter of `.Add` and not `Action<Shape, int>` - you can't decompile lambdas to extract parameters, but you can compile expression to run them (and indeed can extract parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If your enumerator implementation is 'Shape' aware, then you can cast items from your `routines` and get a shape.

```
public interface IShapedEnumerator : IEnumerator {
  Shape EnumeratorShape {get; }
}

pblic class ShapedIteratorProxy : IShapedEnumerator {
  private readonly IEnumerator _baseEnumerator;
  private readonly Shape _shape;
  public Shape EnumeratorShape => _shape;

  public ShapedIteratorProxy (Shape shape, IEnumerator baseEnumerator) {
    _baseEnumerator = baseEnumerator;
    _shape = shape;
  }

  public ShapedIteratorProxy (Shape shape, float arg, Func<Shape, float, IEnumerator> operation)
    : this(shape, operation(shape, arg)) 
  {}
  // implementation of IEnumerator that proxy all calls to _baseEnumerator.
  // ...
}

routines.Add(new ShapedIteratorProxy(Shape.SQUARE, Move(Shape.SQUARE, 1)));
routines.Add(new ShapedIteratorProxy(Shape.CIRCLE, 1, Jump);
routines.Add(new ShapedIteratorProxy(Shape.TRIANGLE, 1, Fire);

var shapes = routines.OfType<IShapedEnumerator>()
                     .Select(s=>s.EnumeratorShape)
                     .ToArray();
```

Please note, that if `routines` contain items that do not implement `IShapedEnumerator`, they will be just skipped.

Comment: I'm not running `Move`, but only creating an instance of it instead, so I don't think this applies, but maybe I can create a class that contains a shape and a IEnumerator attribute that receives these functions (like `Move`) and set it all up in the constructor...

Comment: In your question you call `routines.Add(Move(Shape.SQUARE, 1));` so it is called. I don't undertstand what you mean under `creating an instance of it instead`. `IEnumerator` is not an attribute, this is interface and `Move` returns and instance of class that implements this interface. Not sure I follow your concerns in this comment. Please elaborate. I changed answer to do not change `Move()` method

Comment: In Unity, an `IEnumerator` is only executed when you call it using `StartCoroutine` (e.g. `StartCoroutine(Move(Shape.SQUARE, 1))`).

Comment: *`IEnumerator is not an attribute, this is interface and Move returns and instance of class that implements this interface.`* While technically true, that's not how it works. The point of an IEnumerator is to execute some code, hit a `yield` and return at some later point. When you call `Move()`, the code is executed *immediately* and all you're storing in your array is a pointer back to the code that got "put on hold." I think you're looking for `delegate`s, `Actions`, or events.